# Help with the solution to the Cauchy problem of the firdst order partial differential equation (quasi linear case)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

I am looking for the help with the solution to the following PDE (along with IC):
$$ uu_x + u_t = u, u(x, 0) = 2x $$

Solution (without parameterization):
Applying the method of characteristics one can get the following system of ODEs:
$$\frac{dx}{u} = \frac{dt}{1} = \frac{du}{u}$$
Combaining first and third:
$$\frac{dx}{u} =\frac{du}{u} \Rightarrow du = dx \Rightarrow u = x + C_1$$
Thus, $\boxed{C_1 = u - x}$

Combaining second and third:
$$\frac{dt}{1} = \frac{du}{u} \Rightarrow \frac{du}{u} = dt \Rightarrow \ln(u) = t + C_2 \Rightarrow u = C_2e^{t}$$
Thus, $\boxed{C_2 = ue^{-t}}$

Taking into an account that, in general the arbitrary constant is an arbitrary function, we can write $C_2 = G(C_1)$:

$$ue^{-t} = G(u - x)$$

Using the IC one can substitute it into the equation above, getting the following:
$$2xe^{0} = G(2x - x) \text{ or } G(x) = 2x$$
Nowing how the arbitrary function does work (give to the function the argument and it gives you back the argument multiplied by 2), the particular solution becomes:
$$u = e^{t}(u-x)\cdot 2 \Rightarrow u = 2ue^{t} - 2xe^{t} \Rightarrow u(1-2e^{t}) = - 2xe^{t} \Rightarrow u(x,t) = \frac{2xe^{t}}{2e^{t} - 1}$$

The answer to this problem, unfortunately, $u(x,t) = \frac{2xe^{t}}{2e^{t} \boxed{+} 1}$. I do not get how in the denominator they got plus. Can someone explain it?

P.S. Sorry for my English, I am not native speaker.

Comment: Your solution satisfies the initial condition $u(x,0)=2x$, whereas the "correct" answer does not.

Comment: Thus, it may be a typo in the book